# restoreCompletedTransactions never calls updatedTransactions in StoreKit

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, storekit

I've been banging my head against the wall for a few days with this, since everything used to work fine, but now that I've moved to `Mountain Lion`, `XCode 4.5` and `iOS5.1` and `iOS6`, this issue came along and I thought it might be related to the configuration switch.

I call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` and moments later `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is called, but there is no sign of any call to `updatedTransactions`. It's like the request got lost in space.

I'm also having a possibly related problem with purchases. If I try to repurchase an item using makePurchase, which from what I understand should also lead to a SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored, I get the `"Already purchased.. download"` message followed by the dreaded `"Cannot connect to iTunes store..."` with a `"PaymentTransactionStateFailed"` error code 2. What is error code 2?

The item is a normal non-consumable in-app puchase, and this happens when testing the `StoreKit` in sandbox mode.

I'm seeing others on this forum with similar issues with the only reply being that this is an intermittent bug i the StoreKit. Is this still the most plausible case?

Any news on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I see that this question is a year old.  I am experiencing the exact same problem as described above.  I wish to store the purchased items once returned by updatedTrasactions locally to retrieve them on application startup.  

In addition, I have added a new test user to resolve the "broken test user" case and still no joy.

I do have the observer started in viewDidLoad:  [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

Please help us!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the purchase history [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747457/clearing-purchases-from-ios-in-app-purchase-sandbox-for-a-test-user/69950103#69950103), or the user has never made a purchase before. `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` will never be called. You need to add `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`. Also to be sure check

> queue.transactions.count == 0

All code here:

```
public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
            print("paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished",queue.transactions.count)
            if queue.transactions.count == 0 {
                //call FailedNotification
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is only called when the state of transactions has changed.

If there are no previous transactions `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` will not change the state of these transactions (because there are none) so `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is called without a call to `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`

> I'm also having a possibly related problem with purchases. If I try to repurchase an item using makePurchase, which from what I understand should also lead to a SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored, I get the "Already purchased.. download" message followed by the dreaded "Cannot connect to iTunes store..." with a "PaymentTransactionStateFailed" error code 2. What is error code 2?

You need to call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:]` after handling a successful transaction.